# MVC pattern in Qt4 - how to organize code besides using Interview

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, design-patterns, qt4

i was recently suggested to use MVC pattern to organize my Qt4 application.
I'm a little puzzled :).

How do I implement:
1. model
2. view
3. controller

In HTTP based apps its quite straigtforward. But here I'm not sure what is a view and what is a controller ?

Lets asume that I'm not using Interview right now.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at this like this:

1. Controller is the window/form that You created. Member functions in this class should handle all user input  and call apropriate member functions in your model.
2. Model is your class that handles data and implements other logic.
3. Views are qt widgets used to design your forms/windows
   (You could also treat *.ui files as views and Classes that are bound with ui files as controllers)

Hope this helps.